# Regex to Exclude Double spaces

Tags: asp.net, regex, string

I am looking for a regular expression for c# asp.net 3.5 that will fail if there are ever any double spaces in a sentence or group of words.

```
the cat chased the dog = true
the  cat  chased  the dog = false (doubles spaces occur at random intervals)
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
^((?!\s{2}).)*$
```

In this expression `(?!\s{2}).` matches every character except whitespace ones, followed by another whitespace.

Comment: @Ian: Just out of curiosity, try it with a non-capturing group: `^(?:(?!\s{2}).)*$`

Comment: @Ian: No clue why this might be, sorry. Goold old "Works for me". =)

Answer (score 4):

Do you even need to use regexs? Why not try:

```
string test = "the  cat  chased  the dog";
bool containsDoubleSpaces = test.Contains("  ");
```

Answer (score 1):

your regexp is just this : `"  +"` (that's 2 spaces with a + after them)

it will match 2 or more spaces in a row.

Answer (score 0):

`^.*  .*$` or even    (just two spaces) would do the trick. Replace spaces with `\s` if you wish to accomodate any two whitespace charachers in succession (tabs, new lines etc)

Comment: could you supply a full regex to exclude the double spaces?thanks