# Regex to match string up to two consecutive spaces

Tags: .net, regex

I'm using .NET to experiment with regex's.

I'm struggling to compose a regex to capture a segment in a string that ends with two spaces. For example

```
This is a test  Start of next bit
```

How can I capture the first portion of the above string `This is a test`, knowing that the two segments are split by two spaces (`\s` in the regex world)?

I've tried stuff like:

```
This is a test[^\s{2}]
```

but that's getting me nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

A more standard regex than the one that you have would be:

```
This.*?(?=\s{2})
```

It matches any character `.*?` until it encounters the first double `\s` (by the way, `\s` doesn't exactly mean 'space', it means any whitespace, including newlines, carriage returns, formfeeds, tabs).

Or you could try something a little different; match everything as long as they are single 'spaces':

```
This(?:\s\S+)*
```

Then again, it's simpler to split on the double space.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution via this SO question:

[Regex to Exclude Double spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667505/regex-to-exclude-double-spaces)

`This((?!\s{2}).)*`

Will match what I need.

Crazy stuff this regex malarky.